# Iterating through an array of objects C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I am trying to iterate through an array to objects to set different attributes of those objects. The attributes of my objects may change over time.

My code as a simplified example:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
/* class definitions */
};

extern MyClass object;
```

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include MyClass.h

/* Constructors, Destructors, Functions */
```

```
// main.cpp
void reload_objects();

int main()
{
   MyClass object[20];
   reload_objects();
{

void reload_objects();
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      object[i].setProperties(/*args*/);
   }
}
```

I am getting an error `error: No match for 'operator[]' (operand types are ‘MyClass’ and ‘int’)`. If I move the for loop into main it compiles and runs fine.

What is causing this error?

Would it be easier or in some way better to use `std::vector<MyClass> object(20)` in some way?

Comment: It's a matter of scope: `object` is defined in `main` but your function `reload_objects` is not textually contained in `main` so the array `object` is not visible there. Instead your function sees the global variable `extern MyClass object`.

Comment: The scope of variables is so fundamental to C++, that it is introduced quite early on in even the most basic introductory texts.   The fact you are running into this concern indicates that you have started typing code with minimal (possibly even zero) effort to read introductory material.   You need to read that material because it is so fundamental - without the basic effort to acquire that understanding, you're wasting your time and the time of anyone who you ask for help.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Ah so I simply just declared `object` in the wrong scope.

Comment: @Peter You're right, it was a pretty silly thing to miss. Thank you for being so forthright in pointing out such a simple and silly error. I'm so dumb. You must feel really good about yourself to be so smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your given code snippet. You can correct them as i have shown below. I have added comments wherever i have made changes.

**MyClass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
/* class definitions */
public:
MyClass() = default;
};

extern MyClass object[20]; //declare object as an array 

#endif
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

/* Constructors, Destructors, Functions */
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

 MyClass object[20];    // define object here instead of inside main()
void reload_objects();  // reload_objects() doesnt take any argument by looking at its call and definiton

int main()
{
  // MyClass object[20]; //don't define object here
   reload_objects();
}

void reload_objects()  //you had a semicolon here so i removed it
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      object[i].setProperties(/*args*/);
      ;
   }
}
```

Also **don't forget** to add the definition and declaration of your other member functions like setProperties in the above example for it to work. These are some of the changes that i made:

1. You should declare `object` as an array of size 20 inside MyClass.h.
2. Define `object` outside of main() inside main.cpp as i did in my example.
3. Declare the function reload_objects() with no arguments in main.cpp.

Comment: Some of the errors came from just the way I tried to simplify the code for this question. It seems I simply just declared the object in the wrong scope. Now looks like such a silly thing to miss. Thanks!